# Не могу опубликовать приложение в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

В общем всю нужную инфу заполнил, все сделал, `.apk` залил но мне пишет что

> Не все стабильные версии были внедрены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: что нужно сделать, что бы можно было опубликовать приложение!?

Comment: нажмите изменить версию и там залейте апк файл и все

Comment: @Cypher .apk уже был залит, надо было удалить->перезалить->сохранить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас сохранился предыдущий проект рабочей версии. Вам надо или его внедрить или удалить проект сей. Нажмите на `Изменить версию` - именно там можно или продолжить внедрение или удалить проект и начать заново.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде так и делал (удалил и начал заново добавлять .apk) возможно не сохранился.

Вариант:удалить проект и начать заново.